# add class after wait and add another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a class to an element. After that I want to wait 5 seconds and add another class to the same element.

But it just adds the first class "bigEntrance" to the element, and doesn't add the second class to the same element.

How can I do that?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  $('#page__about__left__logo').each(function() {
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {

      $(this).addClass("bigEntrance", function () {

        $(this).addClass("floating");

      });

    }

  });
});
```

Comment: `setTimeOut()`..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Noted. Comments removed. Bummer, could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the [`addClass` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) says it accepts a second argument, and nothing in your code tells anything to wait five seconds.

To do what you're doing, just add the class and use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to add the next class five seconds later:

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.addClass("bigEntrance");
setTimeout(function() {
    $this.addClass("floating");
}, 5000);
```